# ajax method ($.post) with mysql not working simple code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i have problem this code not working , i want display result of mysql without send no data 
my simple code ajax

```
$('.myClass').on('click',function(){


    $.post('resultAll.php');
});
```

code html

```
<li class="myClass" > click this </li>
```

code php / mysql for display result on page (name resultAll.php)

```
 $stmt = $connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE price = :aff');
$stmt->execute(array(':aff'=>'5'));
$res = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
foreach ($res as $row) {

    ?>
    <div class="noon" style="width: 1000px;height: 500px">
        <?php print_r($row['id'].' ');  ?>
    </div>
```

result these nothing

Comment: Remove the double colon in `$stmt->execute(array(':aff'=>'5'));` if you are using PDO or mysqli or share the code behind `$stmt->execute`

Comment: So is it the PHP code that doesn't work or the POST through jQuery? Because your POST sends nothing and does nothing with the response at least.

Comment: jquery code not working

Answer (score 0):

As per your code snippet, you want to fetch data from resultAll.php file into your HTML page. If I am correct then your code is wrong, you have to use below method instead of `$.post()` method

```
$('.myClass').on('click',function(){
    $("#result").load('resultAll.php');
});
```

Your HTML code should be

```
<li class="myClass" > click this </li>

....
...

<div id="result"></div>
```

I mean in your page must have one div tag with `id="result"`.

I hope this is works for you.

Answer (score 0):

As you say that your Jquery is not working. Is your element `.myClass` is created with JS dynamically? Ensure this:

`$(document.body).on('click', '.myClass', function(){
   $.post('resultAll.php');
});`

**Edit**

Add response from `$.post` to body:

```
$('.myClass').click(function(){
    $.post('resultAll.php', function(response){
        $(body).append(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: jquery correct but does not display anything , i want just display result mysql  code of page resultAll.php . $.post('resultAll.php') does not run that my problem